# Where to discuss family/relatives/people related problems about their behavior

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

Where can I discuss family related problems, dealing with certain situations among relatives about their behavior and my actions?

Comment: [SE Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) maybe.

Comment: @user0042 The site says "Parenting Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role.". I think it is not.

Comment: Usually that was the kitchen table, but you might be more comfortable doing this in the living room.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be acceptable on [Interpersonal SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com). Please be sure to read their [help centre](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help) and [on-topic pages](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before writing your question. When in doubt search their [meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: Nope, it says "Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people looking to improve their interpersonal communication skills". While i am looking for family/relatives related problems where other people and my decision about other people do matters even neglecting myself or decision against my will/self

Comment: @bjan - have a look at Interpersonal and Parenting. Both have questions that certainly sound like part of what you are alluding to, but you aren't being very clear.